# Losing reputation because of something deleted

Tags: discussion, reputation

I recently noticed that I've lost a small amount of reputation, with the reasoning listed as "user deleted". A few simple questions about this:

- Can I get some elaboration on what this means, if perhaps it doesn't mean exactly what I think it does?
- How can I track what exactly was deleted?
- Why is this system in place?

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4417/removing-of-users and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5122/removal-of-votes-when-a-user-is-removed

Answer (score 3):

When a user is deleted, their votes go, too. If they have upvoted, or downvoted, any of your questions/answers, those votes will be taken back. The bounties that they have awarded are not taken back.

If you keep a record of [your daily reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation), you can search for differences. Otherwise, I have not found a way to find the posts that have lost reputation because a user has been removed.

Although losing reputation is a bit depressing, I can see the logic behind the removal. If this were not done, a user could upvote a number of questions/answers, delete their account, then come back with a new account and upvote the same questions/answers. If their votes were not deleted when they left, one user would have been counted twice for the same question/answer. Since the accounts do not coexist, the scripts to detect reputation fraud would have no way to detect the impropriety.